# How to make my app updating even though auto update is off in Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, bundle, auto-update

I have noticed that facebook and messenger app auto-update themselves on my android phones although I am not enabling auto-updates for them. How can I implement this for my android app?

Comment: do you see option to un-install fb app from your device ? i am asking coz it may fall under pre-installed built in apps.

Comment: it isn't from built in apps

Comment: Then this should definitely not happen. I don't think you app can update itself without asking the user. You could download a newer apk and trigger an install intent but that's not gonna use the play store. also the user will be asked if he really wants to install the new apk.

Comment: @dedda1994 can you explain more how to use an install intent

Comment: Sorry, i'm not at home right now. Just writing on the app. But i'm sure there's plenty of tutorials or other SO posts.

Comment: I can wait until you go home

Answer (score 0):

This definitely should not happen without you agreeing to it (if they are not system apps). If it does it sounds like a pretty serious security bug. You definitely should not even try to implement it for your own app. If you can work out how this is happening, or see it happening you should report it to facebook or Android security.